# How to add edit button only on previous week records in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to add delete button available only for the previous week records.

```
$accounts = Accounts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
return response()->json($accounts);
```

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not matching with your code

Comment: Yes, that's code only I know, I don't have ideas on how to query or add the button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to show your accounts in a view/table.

```
class AccountsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $accounts = Accounts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('accounts.index', compact('accounts'));
    }
}
```

I also assume that the `Account` model has a `created_at` timestamp, which is a [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance. So we can use `isLastWeek()` method. In the `accounts/index.blade.php`, you can do something like:

```php
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Account ID</th>
    <th>Account Name</th>
    <th>Actions</th> 
  </tr>
  @foreach($account as $account)
      <tr>
          <td>{{$account->id}}</td>
          <td>{{$account->name}}</td>
          <td>@if($account->created_at->isLastWeek())<button>Edit</button>@endif</td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach

</table>
```

If you want to use Vue, no problem. Lets update `accounts/index.php` slightly:

```
// accounts/index.blade.php
<accounts-list :accounts="{{$accounts}}"/>
```

We can add a custom attribute to the Account model:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['created_last_week'];

    public function getCreatedLastWeekAttribute()
    {
        return $this->created_at->isLastWeek();
    }
}
```

Then we have the `AccountsList.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr is="account-row" v-for="account in accounts" :account="account" :key="account.id"></tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
</template>

<script>
import AccountRow from './AccountRow.vue'

export default {
    props: ['accounts'],
    components: {AccountRow}
}

</script>
```

Finally, you can make use of the custom attribute `created_last_week` above in the `AccountRow.vue` component.

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>{{account.id}}</td>
        <td>{{account.name}}</td>
        <td><button v-if="account.created_last_week">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['account']
}
</script>
```

Comment: What about using vue?

Comment: @Marky have updated my answer. Hope that answer your question.